# Display records horizontally in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

I need to display database table records horizontally one record after another on my crystal report as in the attached image. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Section Expert, 'Common' tab, turn on the option to 'Format with Multiple Columns'.

A new 'Layout' tab then appears in the Section Expert.
That tab allows you to control how many columns across, sorting, etc.